# Adding displays through usb-c dock crash

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

Have a monitor dock ([https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Monitor-Adapter-450-AEUO-4W2HW/dp/B01C8PHWQY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C8PHWQY)) that I use to plug displays in to. After updating to Ubuntu 17.10 plugging in to either display causes the display server to crash and stop responding. Usually with just blank screen, sometimes just becoming unresponsive.

Occurs with Unity/Ubuntu X-org and Wayland.

Not sure if there is anything I can do to make it more stable anyone have any troubleshooting tips.

EDIT: I got 3 monitors working again but I won't be marking as answered because my doc issues still persist.

I was able to get 1 monitor working by setting the primary laptops display to be 1920x1080. Plugging in the first monitor to the doc's hdmi port and then setting its resolution to 1080 as well. Finally the third one would work.

TLDR change to 1080 before plugging them in.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, just my experience so far:

I've had/have similar issues with the DA200 USB-C Adapter. The only thing I found out was that it could have something to do with enabled GNOME extensions and an erroneous calculation on screen height (or smth. along this way).

Today was the first day I've tried again and so far it did not crash (having installed the newest firmware and all updates)

Comment: afaik I don't have any GNOME extensions installed.  FWIW I can plug one monitor into the dock at a time. But trying to plug a second one in always forces me back to just having 2. The third shows up in the display settings but anytime I try to turn it on it seems like it coerces it back to off or something.